# Randomized convex hull

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-geometry, randomized-algorithms

I've been recently studying Monte-Carlo and other randomized methods for a lot of applications, and one that popped into my mind was making an (approximate) convex hull by examining random points, and try to get them inside the convex hull. I would like to know if there are algorithms for convex hulls that can improve the $O(n \log n)$ bound of comparison based algorithms, and the $O(n\cdot h)$ bound for Jarvis march and related to $O(n)$, either by building an approximate convex hull in $O(n)$ (with or without some approximation criteria) or by building an exact convex hull in expected linear time.

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited to cstheory.

Comment: Did you try to google it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two linear time approximation algorithms in the two-dimensional case are due to [Bentely, Preparata and Faust](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=358392) and [Stojmenović and Soisalon-Soininen](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~ivan/L01-approx-CH.pdf).

A fast exact algorithm which works in expected linear time is due to [Bentley, Clarkson and Levine](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~acosgaya/Research/skyline/p179-bentley.pdf). The paper is quite old, so maybe there are newer developments.